# Is it possible to use a branch logic based on the scoring rank of a participant in Qualtrics?

Tags: qualtrics

In a survey participants are supposed to solve computational tasks and their payment should differ by their rank. How can I compare the scores of the participants within a survey/during a session to determine who has done best, etc.? Is this even possible?

Comment: Your question title references branch logic, which is an "on the fly" decision as any individual respondent performs the tasks, but your question text talks about payments based on rank, which seems to be a "final summation" exercise after every respondent has submitted their work.  Can you explain more about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Of course! The participants are supposed to know their rank after they solved a block of computational problems. Furthermore, their payment is supposed to differ by their rank. Because there are multiple rounds of solving computational problems and they will be paid based on the results of one round which is chosen randomly, I aim to save the possible payment as a variable after each round. Therefore, the branch logic is supposed to work like this: if rank = rank 1 then payment = payment 1, etc.

Comment: Generally speaking, any individual's session within Qualtrics can only "see" its own data, not that of other respondents, so calculating the relative ranks of the respondents has to occur outside the individual sessions.

Comment: It may be possible to implement something like what you're aiming for by having each "round" be a separate survey, and having an intermediate step between each round where a contest administrator runs code to 1) make API calls that pull down the data from the previous round into an environment where 2) the ranks can be calculated and then 3) more API calls populate a contact list for the next survey, including embedded data fields that track their ranked performance from the prior round.  But that wouldn't be a fully automatic process.

Comment: All right, thank you!